# Using mod_rewrite only if a 404 would have occured

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, content-management-system

I am in the process of converting a static website into one using a cms.
I have the cms installed in a sub directory of the public directory. To avoid ending up with ugly domain names (*http://example.com/cms/*) is there an easy way using mod_rewrite to rewrite *http://example.com/…* to *http://example.com/cms/…* while ensuring that if the request wouldn't have ended in a 404, there is no redirect.

An example:

```
/
/cms/index.html
/cms/file.dat
/file.dat
```

If the user requests /index.html, they should get redirected to /cms/index.html, but if they request /file.dat, they *shouldn't* get redirected to /cms/file.dat because the file existed at the requested place

**EDIT**
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Make sure that if the `/cms/index.html` is not the intended page, your server actually returns a 404 response. It probably is intended for `/index.html`, but not for say `/fil.dat`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [RewriteCond Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to check whether there is an existing file that correspond to the requested URL, and only rewrite to your CMS if there is none.

Here is a simple example :

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

If there is no existing file that correspond to the requested URL, then that request is rewritten to `index.php`

You might also want to check for symbolic links and / or directories, btw...

For instance, here is a [possibility that can be used when setting up a Zend Framework project](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.html#zend.controller.quickstart.go.rewrite) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

*(Even though it links to ZF, it should be OK for quite many projects)*

Answer (score 2):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^cms/ cms%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```