# Apache2 configuration that ONLY reverse proxies resources that 404 locally

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I'm trying and failing to create a working configuration for apache2 which does the following:

- Resolves resources local either by returning the static file or running some PHP
- If a 404 is to be returned checks against the reverse proxy
- If the reverse proxy returns a 404 return the local ErrorDocument

I want to do something like

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(?!200).+
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
ProxyErrorOverride On
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

The problem here is that ProxyPassMatch only works on the URL not the status code. Now in nginx I can use this configuration to do what I want.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args @fwd;
}

location @fwd{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can implement my nginx configuration in apache2?

EDIT

I feel like something like this should work (which I got by taking a look at this answer [Using mod_rewrite only if a 404 would have occured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582673/using-mod-rewrite-only-if-a-404-would-have-occured))

```
<Location /[a-z]+/>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080
</Location>
```

I've also tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d                                                                                                                                                                                      RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ - [P]
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [L,P]
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
```

This seems to work but only on static files. It doesn't work on any PHP that might be rendered, not sure why

```
RewriteCond /var/www/html_apache/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "/$1" [S=1]
RewriteRule ^ - [P]
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RewriteCond file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320684/rewritecond-file-exists)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help

Comment: I wasn't really asking if it helped - I was closing your question as a duplicate / SO adds this automatically. This is how you solve your problem simply. But you need to map the proxy mount to a location which doesn't exist and rewrite your URL to match that.

Comment: It's not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While "[RewriteCond file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320684/rewritecond-file-exists)" is not an exact duplicate, it includes an important reminder:

> Remember that `RewriteCond` with `-f` or `-d` needs full path to the file or directory that's why you need to prefix the filename with `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/`.

For example, this configuration first checks if the requested URI corresponds to a real file or directory in the document root.

- If it does, the request is served directly and the rewriting process stops (`[L]` flag).
- If the requested URI does not correspond to a real file or directory, the request is proxied to the backend server (`[P]` flag).

```ini
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is for a real existing file or directory, serve it directly
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the request is not for a real file or directory, proxy it to the backend
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]

# Set up reverse proxy
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Warning: this would not handle PHP execution. If you want Apache to execute PHP scripts before deciding whether to proxy the request, you will need to make sure you have [`php-fpm`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/install.fpm.php) properly configured, in which case you might need to adjust the `RewriteCond` directives to also consider URIs that correspond to PHP scripts as "real" files.

You can also consider using Apache's [`ErrorDocument` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html) in combination with `mod_rewrite` to handle 404 errors. This approach could potentially be used to implement a fallback to a reverse proxy when a local resource is not found.

```ini
# Enable rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is for a real existing file or directory, serve it directly
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the request is not for a real file or directory, return a 404 error
# The ErrorDocument directive will handle this
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]

# Set up a custom 404 error handler
ErrorDocument 404 /handle404.php
```

In this configuration, `/handle404.php` is a PHP script that proxies the request to the backend server.
Here is a very basic example of what that script might look like:

```php
<?php
$backend_url = 'http://localhost:8080' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$response = file_get_contents($backend_url);

if ($response === false) {
    // The backend server returned a 404 error
    http_response_code(404);
    echo "Not found";
} else {
    // The backend server returned a successful response
    echo $response;
}
```

This script uses PHP's [`file_get_contents` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to send a request to the backend server and capture its response.
If the backend server returns a 404 error, the script sends a 404 response to the client. Otherwise, it echoes the backend server's response.

---

> How exactly would you go about handling the php case?

To handle PHP scripts properly in the Apache configuration, you need to ensure that PHP is executed by Apache before deciding whether to proxy the request. You can achieve this by using `mod_proxy_fcgi` along with `php-fpm`. Here is how you can adjust the configuration:

Assuming `php-fpm` is installed and configured, you then need to configure Apache to it (with necessary modules: `mod_rewrite`, `mod_proxy`, `mod_proxy_fcgi`), meaning you need to tell Apache to pass PHP scripts to `php-fpm` for execution. You can use the [`ProxyPassMatch` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) for this purpose.
While you keep the `mod_rewrite` rules to serve local resources or proxy to a backend shown above, you make sure PHP requests are handled by `php-fpm`.

> All requests go through to the reverse proxy.

This can be due to the placement of the `ProxyPass` directive. The `ProxyPass` directive is executed *before* the `mod_rewrite` rules. That means the proxy will be used for all requests, bypassing the `mod_rewrite` rules.

Instead, let's use a `RewriteRule` directive with `[P]`:

```ini
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your-domain.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/your/local/files

    # Handle PHP scripts with php-fpm
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/path/to/your/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Enable rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On

    # If the request is for a directory, internally redirect to the DirectoryIndex
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*/)$ $1index.php [L]

    # If the request is for a real existing file, serve it directly
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # If the request is not for a real file, proxy it to the backend
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyErrorOverride On

    # Error document for handling 404
    ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/your/error/document.html
</VirtualHost>
```

That includes:

- the `FilesMatch` directive tells Apache to use `php-fpm` for handling PHP scripts. Make sure to set the correct path to your `php-fpm` socket or TCP address and port if using TCP instead of a Unix socket.
- the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives are similar to the previous example and serve files and directories if they exist.
- the request proxied to the backend server, when the file does not exist.
- the *removal* `ProxyPass` directive, in favor of `RewriteRule` with the `[P]` flag instead. This flag tells `mod_rewrite` to proxy the request, effectively replacing the ProxyPass directive, but also ensuring that the rewrite conditions are respected.
- the local `ErrorDocument`, when the backend server returns a 404.
- `ProxyErrorOverride On` tells Apache to handle error responses (like 404) from the proxy target and use the local `ErrorDocument` instead.
- the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` for directories will internally redirect to the `index.php` file if the request URI corresponds to a directory. This essentially mimics the `DirectoryIndex` directive.

Comment: How exactly would you go about handling the php case?

Comment: Sorry I've tried those changes out and the PHP isn't rendered, all requests go through to the reverse proxy. https://pastebin.com/ABG7Gvgr

Comment: @user3476571 OK. I have removed the `ProxyPass` and replaced it with a `RewriteRule`. See my edited answer.

Comment: So this is *almost* working. static resources work, php works, 404s proxy BUT if the proxy returns a 404 the ErrorDocument is not returned and the DirectoryIndex page doesn't seem to be respected either.

Comment: @user3476571 OK, I have updated the configuration to take the ErrorDocument and the DirectoryIndex page into account.

Comment: Thanks so much! Definitely not as nice as nginx but basically does what I want now

Comment: @user3476571 I prefer [Caddy server](https://caddyserver.com/v2) personally. But this should work indeed.